# Merge two lists of dicts of different lengths using a single key in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, merge

I want to merge two lists of dictionaries on a single key, when the two lists are different lengths (using Python 3.6). For example, if we have a list of dicts called `l1`:

```
l1 = [{'pcd_sector': 'ABDC', 'coverage_2014': '100'},
       {'pcd_sector': 'DEFG', 'coverage_2014': '0'}]
```

and another list of dicts called `l2`:

```
l2 = [{'pcd_sector': 'ABDC', 'asset': '3G', 'asset_id': '2gs'},
      {'pcd_sector': 'ABDC', 'asset': '4G', 'asset_id': '7jd'},
      {'pcd_sector': 'DEFG', 'asset': '3G', 'asset_id': '3je'},
      {'pcd_sector': 'DEFG', 'asset': '4G', 'asset_id': '8js'},
      {'pcd_sector': 'CDEF', 'asset': '3G', 'asset_id': '4jd'}]
```

How would one merge them using `pcd_sector` to get this(?):

```
result = [{'pcd_sector': 'ABDC', 'asset': '3G', 'asset_id': '2gs', 'coverage_2014': '100'},
          {'pcd_sector': 'ABDC', 'asset': '4G', 'asset_id': '7jd', 'coverage_2014': '100'},
          {'pcd_sector': 'DEFG', 'asset': '3G', 'asset_id': '3je', 'coverage_2014': '0'},
          {'pcd_sector': 'DEFG', 'asset': '4G', 'asset_id': '8js', 'coverage_2014': '0'},
          {'pcd_sector': 'CDEF', 'asset': '3G', 'asset_id': '4jd'}]
```

**What I have tried so far**

I've used the following code to merge the two lists, but I end up with a short version unfortunately, not the desired complete data structure.

```
import pprint
grouped = {}
for d in l1 + l2:
    grouped.setdefault(d['pcd_sector'], {'asset':0, 'asset_id':0, 'coverage_2014':0}).update(d)
result = [d for d in grouped.values()]
pprint.pprint(result)
```

So when I run the code, I end up with this short output:

```
result = [{'pcd_sector': 'ABDC', 'asset': '3G', 'asset_id': '2gs', 'coverage_2014': '100'},
         {'pcd_sector': 'DEFG', 'asset': '4G', 'asset_id': '8js', 'coverage_2014': '0'},
         {'pcd_sector': 'CDEF', 'asset': '3G', 'asset_id': '4jd'}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Problem

The problem in your approach is that your data is put in a `grouped` dict with `'pcd_sector'` as keys but your `l2` has multiple dicts with the same `'pcd_sector'`. You could use a tuple of `'pcd_sector', 'asset'` as key for `l2`, but it wouldn't work for `l1` anymore. So you need to do the processing in two steps instead of iterating on `l1 + l2` directly.

## Theory

If `pcd_sector` keys are unique in `l1`, you can create a big dict instead of a list of small dicts:

```
>>> d1 = {d['pcd_sector']:d for d in l1}
>>> d1
{'ABDC': {'pcd_sector': 'ABDC', 'coverage_2014': '100'}, 'DEFG': {'pcd_sector': 'DEFG', 'coverage_2014': '0'}}
```

Then, you simply need to merge the dicts that have the same `pcd_sector` keys:

```
>>> [dict(d, **d1.get(d['pcd_sector'], {})) for d in l2]
[{'asset_id': '2gs', 'coverage_2014': '100', 'pcd_sector': 'ABDC', 'asset': '3G'}, {'asset_id': '7jd', 'coverage_2014': '100', 'pcd_sector': 'ABDC', 'asset': '4G'}, {'asset_id': '3je', 'coverage_2014': '0', 'pcd_sector': 'DEFG', 'asset': '3G'}, {'asset_id': '8js', 'coverage_2014': '0', 'pcd_sector': 'DEFG', 'asset': '4G'}, {'asset_id': '4jd', 'pcd_sector': 'CDEF', 'asset': '3G'}]
```

## Complete code

Putting it all together, the code becomes:

```
l1 = [{'pcd_sector': 'ABDC', 'coverage_2014': '100'},
       {'pcd_sector': 'DEFG', 'coverage_2014': '0'}]

l2 = [{'pcd_sector': 'ABDC', 'asset': '3G', 'asset_id': '2gs'},
      {'pcd_sector': 'ABDC', 'asset': '4G', 'asset_id': '7jd'},
      {'pcd_sector': 'DEFG', 'asset': '3G', 'asset_id': '3je'},
      {'pcd_sector': 'DEFG', 'asset': '4G', 'asset_id': '8js'},
      {'pcd_sector': 'CDEF', 'asset': '3G', 'asset_id': '4jd'}]

d1 = {d['pcd_sector']:d for d in l1}
result = [dict(d, **d1.get(d['pcd_sector'], {})) for d in l2]

import pprint
pprint.pprint(result)
#   [{'asset': '3G',
#     'asset_id': '2gs',
#     'coverage_2014': '100',
#     'pcd_sector': 'ABDC'},
#    {'asset': '4G',
#     'asset_id': '7jd',
#     'coverage_2014': '100',
#     'pcd_sector': 'ABDC'},
#    {'asset': '3G',
#     'asset_id': '3je',
#     'coverage_2014': '0',
#     'pcd_sector': 'DEFG'},
#    {'asset': '4G',
#     'asset_id': '8js',
#     'coverage_2014': '0',
#     'pcd_sector': 'DEFG'},
#    {'asset': '3G', 'asset_id': '4jd', 'pcd_sector': 'CDEF'}]
```

Comment: This workede great, thanks for the combined theory and complete code answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a lookup dictionary based on `pcd_sector` and just update your original list of dicts based on that:

```
>>> import copy
>>> lookup = { x['pcd_sector'] : x for x in l1 }
>>> result = copy.deepcopy(l2)
>>> for d in result:
...     d.update(lookup.get(d['pcd_sector'], {})) # golfed courtesy Ashwini Chaudhary
... 
>>> result
[{'pcd_sector': 'ABDC', 'asset': '3G', 'asset_id': '2gs', 'coverage_2014': '100'}, 
{'pcd_sector': 'ABDC', 'asset': '4G', 'asset_id': '7jd', 'coverage_2014': '100'}, 
{'pcd_sector': 'DEFG', 'asset': '3G', 'asset_id': '3je', 'coverage_2014': '0'}, 
{'pcd_sector': 'DEFG', 'asset': '4G', 'asset_id': '8js', 'coverage_2014': '0'},
{'pcd_sector': 'CDEF', 'asset': '3G', 'asset_id': '4jd'}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggested answer Coldspeed. In the end I opted for Eric's answer as it provided both theory and complete code sections.

Answer (score 0):

A solution using [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/):

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(l1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(l2)
dfr = df1.join(df2, how='outer')
print(dfr)
```

Output:

```
  coverage_2014 pcd_sector asset asset_id
0           100       ABDC    3G      2gs
1           100       ABDC    4G      7jd
2             0       DEFG    3G      3je
3             0       DEFG    4G      8js
4           NaN       CDEF    3G      4jd
```

If you want it as a dictionary again:

```
result = dfr.to_dict('records')
print(result)
```

Output (with linebreaks added):

```
[{'coverage_2014': '100', 'pcd_sector': 'ABDC', 'asset': '3G', 'asset_id': '2gs'},
 {'coverage_2014': '100', 'pcd_sector': 'ABDC', 'asset': '4G', 'asset_id': '7jd'},
 {'coverage_2014': '0', 'pcd_sector': 'DEFG', 'asset': '3G', 'asset_id': '3je'},
 {'coverage_2014': '0', 'pcd_sector': 'DEFG', 'asset': '4G', 'asset_id': '8js'},
 {'coverage_2014': nan, 'pcd_sector': 'CDEF', 'asset': '3G', 'asset_id': '4jd'}]
```

Comment: Nice. Don't you need to specify which columns you use for lookup?

Comment: You can pass columns explicitly to the `on` keyword argument, but I was under the impression that not doing so would automatically find matching column names between the dataframes, and that is how the code seems to behave. However, [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) seems to indicate otherwise (namely using the index), so I'm not sure now...